# Randomly taking black/white pebbles, unspecified number of each

Tags: probability

**Question:**

> You have a box with $n$ white pebbles and $n$ black pebbles, so $2n$ total. You take half of the pebbles and throw them away. Out of the remaining pebbles, you take one at random(all pebbles are equally probable). What are the odds that the pebble is white?

**My attempt:**

I'm really not sure how to go about this problem, can I even get a solution that depends solely on $n$?

Let's say we have $n-k$ white pebbles, and $n-p$ black pebbles left, and we take one. Odds of it being white is $\frac{n-k}{2n-k-p}$, but I doubt that's the wanted solution.

I can simplify it further, but it still depends on either $k$ or $p$. Since $n-k+n-p = n$, it follows that $p = n-k$ so the probability is now $\frac{n-k}{n}$.

Comment: If the answer were anything other than $1/2$, then the intermediate step of throwing away half the pebbles would somehow favor throwing away more of a particular color.

Comment: Not sure how that comment is helpful for someone who is obviously a beginner in probabilty, but nevermind, nicer people gave an actual answer.

Comment: The point of Math Stack Exchange is not to spoon-feed people answers to elementary problems, but to give them tools/tricks that can let them solve the problem themselves - including elegant big-picture conceptual approaches like the one @BarryCipra suggested (which are very common in higher math) rather than brute-force attacks on the problem. If your response to people taking that approach is to attack them for not being "nice" enough, then I'm afraid that you're going to remain a beginner in probability for a very long time.

Comment: @tparker if you are really going to compare the effort of that comment with the answers below then your opinion is hardly relevant. Giving me the solution, when I'm obviously just stuck on one specific step is a hint? It's helpful? Okay mate, whatever you say! I didnt come here to be spoon-fed, I came because I needed help with a specific step, which I literally described as best as I could. You could have the decency to remain polite,t the least. I guess everyone's entitled to their own opinion, lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to see that $k$ can take values between $0$ and $n$ incusive (There are only $n$ white pebbles). And all of these values are equally probable. Thus you can just "average out" the probabilities $\frac {n-k} n$ for the aforesaid values of $k$. This gives you $\frac {\frac {n-0} n + \frac {n-1} n + ... + \frac {n-n} n} {n + 1} = \frac 1 2$. We can do a simple test for small $n$, e. g. $n = 2,3$, but you can do that yourself.

Comment: Wouldn't you also take into account the first event i.e. the event of throwing away the first $n$ balls? Your answer is valid if you were given a box containing $n-k$ white and $k$ black balls. But, since you're initially given $2n$ balls, you'll also want to first calculate the probability that you actually arrive at a box with $n-k$ white and $k$ black balls, after throwing away the first $n$ balls.

Answer (score 1):

There are $n+1$ different cases for the event that you take $n$ balls out of the box and throw them away.

Let in one such case, $n$ balls be thrown in which $m (0\le m\le n)$ are white and $(n-m)$ are black. Probability of this occurring is $$p_1=\frac{^nC_m\cdot^{n}C_{n-m}}{^{2n}C_n}=\frac{(^nC_m)^2}{^{2n}C_n}$$

Now, the probablity of selecting a white ball on a single draw of the remaining lot ($n-m$ white and $m$ black balls) is:

$$p_2=\frac{n-m}{n}$$

Then, final probability is $$p=p_1\cdot p_2$$

which certainly depends on $m$.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Could you just clarify, or give me a link with an explanation of that notation you used in the expression $p_1=$ since I've never seen it before.
But I get the general idea, thank you very much!

Comment: @DBoss [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations). It is taught in the elementary lectures of counting and permutations. You might have used a different notation listed in the link, if you've studied this subject.

Comment: I see, thanks! I did use a different notation.